# Focus changes on list view click

Tags: android

I'm using a list view to display an array of numbers. On a click event I'm using a number picker, my aim is to show a number picker that can change the number in real time [can be seen in text view of the list while scrolling number picker].

If I click on top objects, the number picker should be shown at the bottom and vice versa. Problem is: if the list is greater than screen size, it enables scrolling, an on click event focus refreshes and the number picker comes according to the refreshed screen state. Also, a user is not able to see the bottom last number changing. Number is changing actually, but the user is not able to see it while changing via number picker.

Let's say my array size is 50  and the screen at once can show 10 numbers. On selecting the 45th element on click event screen focus goes to top 10 elements. I want screen focus to stay there. 
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Dialog Number_Picker_Dialog;
    Display display;
    ArrayList<DataValues> dataValue = new ArrayList<DataValues>();
    public ListView list;
    int checkorient;
    int widthOfScreen,heightOfScreen;   


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        display=((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 

        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.audiogram);
        DataObjects();
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthOfScreen = size.x;
        heightOfScreen = size.y;
        checkorient = getscrOrientation();
        switch(checkorient){
        case 0: Log.i("Orientation","Portrait "+checkorient);break;
        case 1: Log.i("Orientation","Landscape "+checkorient);break;
        default:Log.i("Orientation","Undefined"); break;}
        update();//update method call       

    }   

        public void DataObjects() //Default Values
    { 
        DataValues obj1= new DataValues();
        obj1.setValue1(2500);
        obj1.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj1);

        DataValues obj2= new DataValues();
        obj2= new DataValues();
        obj2.setValue1(2500);
        obj2.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj2);

        DataValues obj3= new DataValues();
        obj3= new DataValues();
        obj3.setValue1(2500);
        obj3.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj3);

        DataValues obj4= new DataValues();
        obj4= new DataValues();
        obj4.setValue1(2500);
        obj4.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj4);


        DataValues obj5= new DataValues();
        obj5= new DataValues();
        obj5.setValue1(2500);
        obj5.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj5);

        DataValues obj6= new DataValues();
        obj6= new DataValues();
        obj6.setValue1(2500);
        obj6.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj6);

        DataValues obj7= new DataValues();
        obj7= new DataValues();
        obj7.setValue1(2500);
        obj7.setValue2(25);
        dataValue.add(obj7);

        DataValues obj8= new DataValues();
        obj8= new DataValues();
        obj8.setValue1(2500);
        obj8.setValue2(25);     
        dataValue.add(obj8);

        DataValues obj9= new DataValues();
        obj9= new DataValues();
        obj9.setValue1(2500);
        obj9.setValue2(25);     
        dataValue.add(obj9);
        DataValues obj10= new DataValues();
        obj10= new DataValues();
        obj10.setValue1(2500);
        obj10.setValue2(25);        
        dataValue.add(obj10);

        DataValues obj11= new DataValues();
        obj11= new DataValues();
        obj11.setValue1(2500);
        obj11.setValue2(25);        
        dataValue.add(obj11);


    }

    public void update(){   

        CustomBaseAdapter cBaseAdapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataValue);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(cBaseAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    int[] acord;
                    acord =  new int[2];
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(acord);

                    Log.i("adapter"," x "+acord[0]+" y "+acord[1]);  
                    onDialogItemClick(position,acord);
            }
        });


    }

    public int getscrOrientation()
    {
        Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        int orientation = getOrient.getOrientation();
        return orientation; // return value 0 is portrait and 1 is Landscape Mode
    }
    public void onDialogItemClick(final int position,int[] acord){
    //Num picker dialog Properties

        Number_Picker_Dialog=new Dialog(this);
        Number_Picker_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.num);
        Number_Picker_Dialog.setTitle("Frequencies(value)");


        Number_Picker_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);//on background click check

        final NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) Number_Picker_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.pick);
        int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = 51; //int gravity=position+1;
        np1.setMaxValue(NUMBER_OF_VALUES-1);
        np1.setMinValue(0);
        np1.setBackgroundColor(1);
        np1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);




        //===================================================================================================   

        Window window = Number_Picker_Dialog.getWindow();
        window.setDimAmount(0f); // -- Set window dim level
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams params = Number_Picker_Dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        LayoutParams lp = Number_Picker_Dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

       switch(checkorient){
        case 0: lp.width  = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.picker_width);
                lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.picker_height); 
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orientation"+checkorient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Number_Picker_Dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                Log.i("Numpicker","Portrait Desgin");break;
        case 1: lp.width  = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.picker2_width);
                lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.picker2_height); 
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orientation"+checkorient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Number_Picker_Dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                Log.i("Numpicker","Landscape Design");break;
        default:Log.i("Orientation","Undefined"); break;}




        //--------------------Conditions-----------------------
        //new algorithm required**16-12-13
        int io = heightOfScreen/2;
        int x=acord[0],y=acord[1];
        int io2 = io/2;

        while(y<=heightOfScreen){

            if( y<=io)//Top to center click
            {   
            window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            Log.i("GsetN","Top Click"+"pos: "+position+" x "+x+" y "+y);
            break;
            }       
            //Center to Bottom click
            if( y>io)
            {
            Log.i("GsetN","Center Click"+"pos: "+position+" x "+x+" y "+y);
            window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            break;}
            else {window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);Log.v("GsetN","No Case detect for numpicker position");break;}
        }
//======================================================================================================================        
    final String[] displayedValues  = new String[NUMBER_OF_VALUES];

        for(int i=0,j=0;i<NUMBER_OF_VALUES;i++,j+=5){
            displayedValues[i] = Integer.toString(j);}

        np1.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);
//======================================================================================================================
        //on value change listner for changing values

        np1.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
                    oldVal, int newVal) {
                    newVal = Integer.parseInt(displayedValues[np1.getValue()]);
                    DataValues obj = dataValue.get(position);
                    obj.setValue2(newVal);//choosen value loaded in the object
                    update();//update method call-->Recursion
                }
            });

//=================================================================================================================
            Number_Picker_Dialog.show();
    } //onitem dialog click ends here

    public void back(View back){
        //Put here the Parent class name
        //Intent bb=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Parent.class);
        //startActivity(bb);
        finish();//currently set to close
    }

}



    //CustomBaseAdapter.java


    public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context = null;
        private ArrayList<DataValues> data = null;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context appContext, ArrayList<DataValues> dataValue)
        {
            context = appContext;
            data = dataValue;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
            TextView txtView_1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TV1);
            TextView txtView_2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TV2);
            DataValues dataVal = data.get(position);

            txtView_1.setText(""+dataVal.getValue1());
            txtView_2.setText(""+dataVal.getValue2());


            return rowView;//if row View is null may cause nExp
        }

    }
    //-----------------DataValues.java-------//
    public class DataValues {
        private int value1;
        private int value2;

        public int getValue1() {
            return value1;
        }
        public void setValue1(int value1) {
            this.value1 = value1;
        }
        public int getValue2() {
            return value2;
        }
        public void setValue2(int value2) {
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

    }
```